# make international payment on behalf of another company

Tags: united-kingdom, international-transfer, greece, taiwan

A relative of mine is a partner in a company in Greece. The company needs to make an international payment to a company in Taiwan (10.000 EUR) for some equipment they purchased. They do have this sum but because of the capital controls the payment must be approved by a special committee and this will take far too much time. I live in the UK and I happen to have this sum and I'm willing to make the payment on their behalf from my UK bank account (or using TransferWise if possible). They will transfer the same sum to my Greek bank account on the same day, so effectively this isn't a loan.

My concern is: am I going to have any trouble with the HMRC? Could the company have any trouble with the Greek tax authorities?

Comment: How long ago did you acquire this relative?

Comment: This does sound exactly like the set-up of a classic scam. What  guarantee do you have that the Greek transfer will take place? (Remember that even a written contract is probably  unenforceable if it's a conspiracy to bypass the capital controls...) How certain are you that this really is your cousin, and that your cousin can make that deposit happen? Remember that even seeing the money go into your account may not be proof it exists, depending on exactly what happens with their check.

Comment: There is no doubt that I'll get this money back as this person is very close family. My concern is whether or not there can a legal problem.